# H264 Royalty fee in the case of video trimming

Tags: licensing, h.264, mp4

I'm one of the mobile software developers in our company, and currently we plan to develop a video trimming application software. By far there are two way for us, one of them is to buy the whole codec we need from codec vendor, another way is to develop all functions by our self, which will involve legal issue. Currently we are focusing on the feasibility study on the second way, that is, develop by our self, so now we have some questions about the issues of license and royalty fee.

what our application will do is as following steps:

1. Parse mp4 file container
2. Parse frame information to find beginning I frame and ending I frame for trimming.
3. Do video trimming by preserving frame data between begining I frame and ending I frame.
4. Create another mp4 file and put frame data in it.

my questions are:

1. Which step needs license to do it legally, and what license should I request.
2. Is step 2 involves decoding procedure? or is it just header parsing?
3. Does this scenario also apply to the case of WMV?

I've asked the same question to MPEG LA, but they said that they are not in the position to provide technical guidance, thus they can't determine which license is helpful to our case.

Thanks in advance for your kindly help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The only way to really approach this is to consult an attorney who specializes in software licensing (ideally with some experience working with MPEG-LA). Also, just to note, you may still be responsible for royalties even if you license an implementation from a third-party company.
2. Technically speaking it may be possible without decoding/re-encoding. The details will depend on the type of video codec used in the MP4 container. For example, MPEG-2 video with an open GOP structure will not cut cleanly on an I-frame boundary. The situation can get even more complicated with H.264/AVC.
3. Yes, depending on the encoding parameters it may also be possible with WMV.

In general, you need to learn more about what kind of data will be MP4/WMV container. I can tell you from experience that the content of these types of files can vary wildly. Implementing arbitrary trimming of any MP4 or WMV file is a big undertaking. The first thing I would do is see what assumptions can be made about the source files to try and reduce the scope of the work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh OK I got it! Thanks to your valuable information!

Answer (score 1):

I think there is quite a hope for -

**Answer to Q1: Which step needs license to do it legally, and what license should I request.**
1. Patent portfolio applies to patents related to *encoding* and *decoding* - this means algorithms used for *transcoding (unless it is brute force re-encoding)* are patented separately. So these algorithms are *NOT* covered by MPEG-LA. You may infringing some other patent if you copy that idea, but if your method is one of the published methods - it is safe to assume that it is not a case of MPEG encoder licensing.

1. Now since you are parsing and wrapping MP4 - the MP4 file format licensing might just apply. (My belief is MP4 file format is a major (direct) derivation from apples's mov) there is a patent pool (with few patents on them). So since you are *wrapping up* streams back after your processing, that licensing would be straight same to whatever goes to MP4 encoder.

**Answer to Q2: Is step 2 involves decoding procedure? or is it just header parsing?**
1. Broadly it doesn't require *decoding*. It only requires parsing. (We do something similar in our company.) It does involve more than just parsing in situation where you want to cut a picture which is P rather than I. (this depends on application). The frame conversion can be thought of *decoding* however, it can be done without fully decoding; in my belief this would be out of scope from generic decoding license. (Though, confirm this from a lawyer!)

**Answer to Q3: ** 
I don't know.

My general take is - broadly you are more subject to trans-coding and other class of patents in this area rather than what applies to MPEG-LA license pool.

However, there is something else you must remember - getting to development vs. buying off-the-shelf is much more than just a legal issue. Even what looks simpler like "Just-cut-between-I-frame-to-another-I-frame" is not a trivial job. [mostly due to vastness of MPEG standard and context]. It is certainly possible - but with high caliber human resource. So you need to work your way through all engineering problems in the path!

Comment: Advertising (even Area 51 proposals) does not belong in the answers section.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Ok, sorry. Is there any good way to advertise inside stack overflow?

Comment: The advertising info is linked in the footer: http://stackexchange.com/about/contact

Comment: @BilltheLizard well, i meant that i just want to spread awareness about the SO community itself. Nothing to advertise otherwise. What is the appropriate form of communication to other members?

Comment: The site admins may put it into the sidebar advertising rotation on related sites/questions.  See Robert's answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96910/promote-area-51-proposal-on-other-se-sites